# Install Deepin DE

Tags: release-hera, desktop, desktop-environment

Could I install the Deepin Desktop Environment on Elementary OS?I was caught away by it's beauty.I've already seen how to install it on Ubuntu,Debian,etc., wondering if I will have a non-usable OS after installing the DE.I would also like to switch between DDE and Pantheon.

Comment: I mean,if I install it,will my OS break?

Comment: Also,will I be able to select which DE I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically yes you could, but doing so would completely defeat the point of elementary OS, and it could potentially break things.
If you want the Deepin DE you're better off just using the [Deepin OS](https://www.deepin.org/en/download/) or something like [Ubuntu DDE Remix](https://ubuntudde.com/).

Comment: Is there any way to get any window manager?

Comment: Of course. elementary is based on Ubuntu, so anything that can be installed on Ubuntu or is in the Ubuntu repos will work on elementary OS. It's still not recommended though because it may break things on elementary.

Comment: Then,could we change between the window manager and pantheon?